# jQuery constantly ping for Ajax responce

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How can I use jQuery to constantly run a PHP script and get the response every second and also to send small bits of data on mouse down to the same script?

Do I really have to add some random extension just to get such a simple timer to work?

Comment: Getting the response ever second is a bit excessive... can you change this to 15 seconds at least ?

Answer (score 25):

> To iterate is human, to recurse divine.
>   [-L. Peter Deutsch](http://www.devtopics.com/101-great-computer-programming-quotes/)

```
var req = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'http://example.com/yourscript.php',
        complete : function () {
            req();
        }
    });
};
req();
```

In case it's not obvious, the above will make a new request as soon as the previous one completes, forever. You could also set a 1 second delay between requests as follows:

```
var req = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'http://example.com/yourscript.php',
        complete : function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                req();
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
};
req();
```

Comment: This will occur many times a second and bring the server down with its load

Comment: I presume you downvoted before I added the 2nd version. The basic idea is to use a callback rather than simply polling once per second.

Comment: And, anyway, it won't make many requests per second. It will make 1 request at a time. 1 request, when it completes, make the next request. So, maybe you should undo your downvote?

Comment: Andrew's right, that code not only works, it is exactly what Steve asked for.

Comment: This will generally work ok - though I think a more robust approach is to have the response tell the application how long it should wait before contacting the server again, as it's often in a position to calculate an optimal duration.

Comment: Sure, this is a stripped down case. What it *should* do is inspect the response as you say and decide whether *and* when to make the next one.

Comment: Elegant and perfect solution

Answer (score 1):

```
function doAjax(data){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    url: 'http://example.com/yourscript.php',
  });
}
// Set interval
setInterval('doAjax()',1000);
// Set event handler
$(document).mousedown(function(){
  doAjax({key: 'value'});
});
```

You could replace $(document) with an actual element if you don't want to capture clicks on the whole page.

You can do a lot more with the ajax function if you are looking for callbacks etc:
http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax

Answer (score 1):

//All pings you need:

```
ping.pushCallback(function() { YourCallback(); });
$.data(document.body, 'data_ping', ping);
```

//------------------------------------------------------
//Script

```
$.ping = function(url, options) {
    this.url = url;
    this.options = $.extend({
        delay: 2000,
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 10000,
        data: {},
        callbacks: []
    }, options);
    this.queue();
};
$.ping.prototype = {
    queue: function() { var self = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            self.send();
        }, self.options.delay);
    },
    send: function() { var self = this;
        $.ajax(self.url, {
            success: function(data) {
                for (var i in self.options.callbacks) {
                    self.options.callbacks[i](data);
                }
            },
            complete: function() {
                self.queue();
            },
            dataType: self.options.dataType,
            data: self.options.data,
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            timeout: self.options.timeout
        });
    },
    setData: function(key, value) { 
        this.options.data[key] = value;
    },
    pushCallback: function(callback) {
        this.options.callbacks.push(callback);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add some random extension. There are native javascript functions [setInterval and setTimeout](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/) for doing stuff on set intervals. You would probably want to do something like

```
function ajaxPing() {
  ...
}

setInterval("ajaxPing()", 1000);

$(element).mousedown(ajaxPing);
```

On the other hand, if you really want to do the pinging **every second**, it would probably be sufficient to just store your data in variables on `mousedown` and submit it on next ping (that will happen in less than a second).

Answer (score 0):

You can put the code for pinging the server in a function, then do something like this:

```
setInterval('ping()',1000); //this will ping 1000 milliseconds or 1 second
```