# Calling self executing anonymous parent function in JS

Tags: javascript

**given the following code**

```
(function(){console.log("ello");setTimeout("**CALL PARENT FUNCTION**",100);}())
```

*how would one call this anonymous parent function every X duration..*

Comment: The title should be changed to "Recursively calls to immediately invoked function expression". There is no such thing as an "anonymous function" in JavaScript. What you've written is a "function expression" - what you need is a "named function expression" so that it can be called from within its own function body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`callee` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee) on the `arguments` object:

```
(function(){console.log("ello");setTimeout(arguments.callee,100);})()
```

It is however, recommended on the [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee) site:

> Note: You should avoid using arguments.callee() and just give every function (expression) a name.

Comment: Do note that `arguments.callee` will throw an error in ES5 strict mode, and is not cross-browser.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to refer to the current function as `arguments.callee`. However, this is prohibited in ECMAScript 5's Strict Mode and will be removed in future editions. If you were going to use it anyway, it would look like this:

```
(function(){console.log("ello");setTimeout(arguments.callee, 100);}())
```

Instead, you should just give the function a name. Because you're using the function as an expression, the name won't be visible to anyone else, you're just giving it a way to refer to itself. This is the recommendation made in [Mozilla's JavaScript docs for `arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee):

> **Note:** You should avoid using `arguments.callee()` and just give every function (expression) a name.

This is simple and shorter than using `arguments.callee`:

```
(function f(){console.log("ello");setTimeout(f, 100);}())
```

Comment: @samccone: This function is practically anonymous; its name is only visible to itself. There are some ways to actually identify the current function but they're deprecated and it's clearer to do this.

Comment: i agree but I wanted to know how to do it with an anonymous function

Comment: +1 for beating me with almost the same answer I just typed (but then didn't bother submitting once I saw yours - stupid slow smartphone keyboard).

Answer (score 1):

You would want to implement recursion.

You can look at:

http://www.devhands.com/2009/06/javascript-recursive-settimeout/

Specifically the section on:

```
function(){
    var t_count = 0;
    (function(delay, count) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (count && ++t_count > count) return;
            // do your stuff here
            setTimeout(arguments.callee, delay);
        }, delay);
    })(200, 10);
}
```

Update:
It is true that arguments.calee was deprecated in javascript, the SO Thread here talks about it: [Why was the arguments.callee.caller property deprecated in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103598/why-was-the-arguments-callee-caller-property-deprecated-in-javascript) , and there is another thread here that talks about how to [stop settimeout in recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995426/stop-settimeout-in-recursive-function) which does have information that you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try arguments.callee

```
console.log("ello"); setTimeout(arguments.callee,100);
```