# JavaScript Clear setTimeout after few secend

Tags: javascript, settimeout

```
function myFunc() {
    console.log('myFunc called');
    if (1 == 2) {
        //When the condition fulfilled clear the setTimeout.
    } else {
        setTimeout(myFunc, 1000);

        // I want to clear the timeout after 10 seconds
    }
};
```

Now myFunc running infinitely.

If the condition didn't match within 10 seconds i want to clear the setTimeout to stop the myFunc call and reload the page using `window.location.reload()`

If the condition fulfilled clear the setTimeout.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [stop settimeout in recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995426/stop-settimeout-in-recursive-function)

Comment: you'll need to track how many seconds have passed since the "original" call to `myFunc`, or how many times `myFunc` has been called. A variable outside of `myFunc` should to the trick.

Comment: Sometimes the condition will always false. That's why i am trying to use reload after 10 seconds.

Comment: reloading will naturally clear the timeout. no running processes will survive the the reload.

Comment: How can i reload after 10 seconds? setInterval(window.location.reload(), 10000) didn't work. Reloading instantly.

Comment: ok i can use setTimeout("location.reload(true);",10000);

Comment: or `setTimeout(location.reload, 10000)` (note the lack of parentheses and use of `setTimeout` and not `setItnterval`).

Comment: setTimeout(location.reload, 10000) gives   "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation" on chrome console.

Comment: Weird. `setTimeout(function() { location.reload() }, 10000)` works fine though. TIL :).

Comment: Ah, it needs the correct `this`; `setTimeout(location.reload.bind(location), 10000);` works too. Sorry for leading you astray.