# Stop all instances of a function when that function is executed - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, kill

I have a function that I would like to stop when the function is called.
How would I do this?
Here is my code:

```
function waitforsend(tdate, messagecontent) { //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22125865/wait-until-flag-true
    cdate = Math.floor(new Date().getTime())/1000 - 18000
    if(cdate <= tdate) {
       setTimeout(function(){
           waitforsend(tdate, messagecontent)
       }, 1000);
    } else {
        client.channels.cache.get(eventchannelid.toString()).send(messagecontent)
        fs.renameSync('./events/' + tdate + '.json', './pastevents/' + tdate + '.json', function(err){
            if(err){
                console.log(colors.red('Issue removing file ' + tdate +', removing file'))
                fs.unlink(tdate + '.json', function(err){
                    if(err){console.log(colors.red('Issue with removing file, please mannualy remove.'))}
                })
            }
        })
        console.log('I got here')
        Scan()
    }
}
```

How can i stop the execution of waitforsend() when Another instance of it is called.
The issue is from calling Scan(), which will read a file and then call waitforsend(). Scan() is also called when a file is created, and this leads to waitforsend() trying to move a file that doesnt exist. How can I solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [stop settimeout in recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995426/stop-settimeout-in-recursive-function)

Comment: No, I just want to stop execution of the function or find a way to have it exit on start if a certain condition is true

Comment: Right, so, you want to stop a setTimeout that's in a function that calls itself. recursively. ;)

Comment: Do you have any better ideas? Im not all that good with js.

Comment: store the id, then clear it when you want to clear it.

Comment: How would I do that? As I said im pretty bad at js 